# Having trouble using an integer model attribute in conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

WOW I JUST SOLVED MY OWN PROBLEM AFTER POSTING THIS: The answer is to just take away the quotation marks for the current_user.bedrooms integer. Can someone tell me if this is because the number is an integer and not a string? Feels great to solve this, but want to know the why.

I am trying to write some conditional to convert the number of bedrooms the current user has into a price for the service.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<p>Price:</p><% if current_user.bedrooms == "1" %>
<%= "$100" %> 
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == "2" %>
<%= "$120" %> 
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == "3" %>
<%= "$140" %>  
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == "4" %>
<%= "$160" %> 
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == "5" %>
<%= "$190" %> 
<% else %>
<%= "$260" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is how the user selected that value on registration:

```
<%= f.label :select_home_size %> 
<%= f.select(:bedrooms, options_for_select([['Studio or 1 bedroom', 1], ['2 bedrooms', 2], ['3 bedrooms', 3], ['4 bedrooms', 4], ['5 bedrooms', 5]])) %>
```

I know something is stored for the current_user.bedrooms attribute, because the following code successfully prints how many bedrooms the user has in integer form (for example "3" for 3 bedrooms):

```
<p><strong>Number of bedrooms:</strong> <%= current_user.bedrooms %></p>
```

For a user with 3 bedrooms, this prints out "3". Confused on what I am doing wrong. I am new to programming and rails, so it is probably something simple I am doing wrong. It just prints out the else statement of "$260", and if I take the else statement away, it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are comparing an integer (current_user.bedrooms) vs a string, that is why it always go to the else statement. You should compare vs integers:

```
<% if current_user.bedrooms == 1 %>
  $100
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == 2 %>
  $120
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == 3 %>
  $140
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == 4 %>
  $160
<% elsif current_user.bedrooms == 5 %>
  $190
<% else %>
  $260
<% end %>
```

Also you can refactor your code a bit too and move it to a helper maybe, like:

```
module ServiceHelper
  def price_for_bedrooms(number_of_bedrooms)
    case number_of_bedrooms
    when 1 then "$100"
    when 2 then "$120"
    when 3 then "$140"
    when 4 then "$160"
    when 5 then "$190"
    else then "$260"
  end
end

 #In your view:
 <p>Price: <%= price_for_bedrooms(current_user.bedrooms) %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! You taught me about these helpers. I really appreciate it!